# VSTS 2017 Kanban board template

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kanban, team-project

I have to customize a Kanban board with new columns, in a Team Project with several Teams, using a custom . I alredy did it in the default Team. The problem is that every Team has a Kanban board, and every Kanban must have the same columns as the default Team. Is there a way to acomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, VSTS/TFS has no such feature to share Kanban template across teams in a project.

I added an user voice [share kanban format across teams](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18851464-share-kanban-format-across-different-teams-in-a-pr), you can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but just use Redbooth's [Kanban Board](http://redbooth.com/kanban-board) Tool.  For the kanban template: create a new workspace - click add templates - then click kanban.  You should be able to do what you want within this tool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).